# How to impose an unrestricted number of calls for the verify method for mockito?

Tags: junit, mockito, easymock

i am trying to convert a code from easymock to mockito. do you have any idea how to convert the method anytimes() from easymock to mockito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use times from `mockito` to achieve same

```
Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.atLeast(0)).methodToVerify(args);
```